# Extract 1 million integer in sorted form with small physical memory

Tags: performance, file, sorting, memory, ram

Given 10 files each having 1 million integer in sorted order, physical memory have size of 3 million. 
Please suggest methods to extract 1 million integer in sorted form efficiently.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Comment: This is just an interview question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deep into details, there's nice book icon from **Knuth** [Sorting and Searching](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896850). It's bestseller in this topic, and gives understanding on the algorithms, which are being used even today.

On StackOverflow, there was really nice discussion, on [how does the **MapReduce** algorithm work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152732/how-does-the-mapreduce-sort-algorithm-work).

Or this discussion from [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128161/sort-algorithms-that-work-on-large-amount-of-data) on sorting algorithms with limited resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 10 way merge. Space for 1 million integers is needed for the result, so the remaining space of 2 million integers is split up into 10 parts, so buffer size for each of the 10 input files is 200,000 integers.